# Laravel 5 Custom validation rule for items in array with reference to other fields

Tags: laravel, validation, rule

I'm trying to figure out how I can validate some data based on some other input. And to make it even more complicated, both the data and the other input are in an array.
Here are the rules:

```
    $rules = [];
    $rules['items.*.articleId'] = ['required', 'integer'];
    $rules['items.*.data'] = ['required', new ItemData()];
```

The way the data is checked should be based on the the articleId of the current item. So the question is if there is a way to know the articleId (of the item) in the ItemData-rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found at least one (somewhat cumbersome) solution:

- Supply the rule with all input
- Parse the $attribute in the `passes` method
- Use this to find the articleId in the input

ItemData class:

```
    namespace App\Rules;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class OrderItemData implements Rule {

        private $_input = null;

        public function __construct($input) {
            $this->_input = $input;
        }

        public function passes($attribute, $value) {
            $idParts = explode('.', $attribute);
            array_pop($idParts);
            $imp = $this->_input;
            foreach ($idParts as $idPart) {
                $imp = $imp[$idPart];
            }

            $articleId = $imp['articleId'];

            // do some checking here..

            return true;
        }

        public function message() {
            return ':attribute is invalid.';
        }
    }
```

Still curious to know if there is a more elegant solution!